# php jwt framework decrypt token Multiple Recipients error

Tags: php, jwt, jwe, jose

```
require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Jose\Component\Core\AlgorithmManager;
use Jose\Component\Encryption\Algorithm\ContentEncryption\A256CBCHS512;
use Jose\Component\Encryption\Algorithm\KeyEncryption\RSAOAEP256;
use Jose\Component\Encryption\Compression\CompressionMethodManager;
use Jose\Component\Encryption\Compression\Deflate;
use Jose\Component\Encryption\JWEBuilder;
use Jose\Component\Encryption\Serializer\CompactSerializer;
use Jose\Component\KeyManagement\JWKFactory;
use Jose\Component\Encryption\JWEDecrypter;

class Multiplereceipient_1 extends CI_Controller {

    private $private_key1;
    private $private_key2;
    private $public_key1;
    private $public_key2;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->private_key1 = "";
        $this->private_key2 = "";
        $this->public_key1 = "";
        $this->public_key2 = "";
    }

    public function index() {
        $payload = json_encode([
            'iat' => time(),
            'nbf' => time(),
            'exp' => time() + 3600,
            'iss' => 'My service',
            'aud' => 'Your application',
        ]);
        $serializedJwe=$this->encrypt($payload);
        
        
    }

    public function encrypt($payload) {
// Create the algorithm manager
        $keyEncryptionAlgorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([
            new RSAOAEP256()
        ]);
        $contentEncryptionAlgorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([
            new A256CBCHS512(),
        ]);

// Create the compression method manager
        $compressionMethodManager = new CompressionMethodManager([
            new Deflate(),
        ]);

// Create the JWE builder
        $jweBuilder = new JWEBuilder(
                $keyEncryptionAlgorithmManager,
                $contentEncryptionAlgorithmManager,
                $compressionMethodManager
        );

// Create the recipients' public keys
        $this->private_key1 = JWKFactory::createRSAKey(
                        2048,
                        [
                            'alg' => 'RSA-OAEP-256',
                            'use' => 'enc'
        ]);
        $this->private_key2 = JWKFactory::createRSAKey(
                        2048,
                        [
                            'alg' => 'RSA-OAEP-256',
                            'use' => 'enc'
        ]);
        $this->public_key1 = $this->private_key1->toPublic();
        $this->public_key2 = $this->private_key2->toPublic();
        $publicKeys = [
            'recipient1' => $this->public_key1,
            'recipient2' => $this->public_key2,
        ];
// Build the JWE for multiple recipients
        $jwe = $jweBuilder
                ->create()
                ->withPayload($payload)
                ->withSharedProtectedHeader([
                    'alg' => 'RSA-OAEP-256',
                    'enc' => 'A256CBC-HS512',
                    'zip' => 'DEF'
                ])
                ->addRecipient($publicKeys['recipient1'])
                ->addRecipient($publicKeys['recipient2'])
                ->build();

// Serialize the JWE to a compact format
        $serializer = new CompactSerializer();
        $serializedJwe = $serializer->serialize($jwe);

        echo "<pre>";
        echo $serializedJwe;
        
        $this->decrypt($serializedJwe,$this->private_key1);
        $this->decrypt($serializedJwe,$this->private_key2);

        
    }

    public function decrypt($serializedJwe,$privateKey) {
        echo "<br>";echo '======';
        // Load the JWE from its serialized for
        $serializer = new CompactSerializer();
        $jwe = $serializer->unserialize($serializedJwe);
       
// Create the algorithm manager
        $keyEncryptionAlgorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([
            new RSAOAEP256()
        ]);
        $contentEncryptionAlgorithmManager = new AlgorithmManager([
            new A256CBCHS512(),
        ]);

// Create the compression method manager
        $compressionMethodManager = new CompressionMethodManager([
            new Deflate(),
        ]);


        
        
// decrypt the JWE
        $decryptedPayload = null;
        //$recipientKey = $privateKeys[$recipient->getHeader('kid')];
        $decrypter = new JWEDecrypter(
                $keyEncryptionAlgorithmManager,
                $contentEncryptionAlgorithmManager,
                $compressionMethodManager
        );

        if ($decrypter->decryptUsingKey($jwe, $privateKey, 0)) {
             echo "<br>";
            $decryptedPayload = $jwe->getPayload();
            echo "<pre>";
            echo $decryptedPayload;
            echo "----";
        }
        
    }

}
```

i am using jwt frame for jwt . using the jwe single recipients i don't face any issue.
But facing problem in multiple recipients.
suppose i have 2 Recipients so in  i need to decrypt 2 times with the private_key and private_key2 and gives me the encrypted data. but i  got the result first times encrypted but the second time(private_key2) do't get and response.

Can some provide the multiple recipients in php ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your token is actually not a multi-recipient one because you use the Compact Serializer which is not designed for that purpose. **You must use the JSON General one**. In addition, **you must set the recipient index** when decrypting the token.

Here is a working example with th modifications mentioned above: https://phpsandbox.io/n/green-owen-lars-outqm